# Flash Player and mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, flash, actionscript-2

I created this very simple Counter in Adobe Flash Professional to be displayed on our website. A working example can be viewed here: [www.feralcatmonth.com/Spay-Neuter-Counter/](http://www.feralcatmonth.com/Spay-Neuter-Counter/)

First, I need to get the 2 buttons when they are clicked to insert a row in a designated mySQL Database, which I have created.

There are two tables in the Database (spay_total & neuter_total) with three columns in each table (ip, clicks, datetime). This could easily be accomplished with only 1 row but I wanted to setup 'ip' as the computer's ip address. `Clicks` is set to auto_increment.

Any help with these issues will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

**EDIT**

I managed to get this Flash Player to work with the XML file. The XML displays the last row in the table but only grabs the `clicks` column from the table. The `clicks` column is set to auto-increment.

The only issue I have now is how to link the button so once it is pushed it adds a row to the database while also increasing the display box by +1.

I think the code will be something like this in Flash Actions Button:

```
on (press) {
      INSERT INTO spay_total (ip, datetime) VALUES ('$ip', 'NOW()');
}
```

But I don't know how to incorporate this into the Flash Player Actions?

As of right now, I do not really care about getting the ip address of the user. I just need to get the button to insert a row into the database, then I will worry about getting the IP address.

Flash Professional Actions Frame (for reference if needed):

```
{
var theXML:XML = new XML();
theXML.ignoreWhite = true;
theXML.load("http://www.feralcatmonth.com/php-sql/spay_totals.php");

theXML.onLoad = function(success){
if (success){
    spay_counter=this.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild;
    }
  };
var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite = true;
myXML.load("http://www.feralcatmonth.com/php-sql/neuter_totals.php");

myXML.onLoad = function(success){
if (success){
    neuter_counter=this.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you again.

Comment: There are still people implementing in flash? Wow. _Why?_

Comment: @arkascha [flashvshtml](http://flashvhtml.com/) Also I just used Flash because that is what I have readily available for prototype/design. Plus I wanted to learn some new skills! I know HTML5 is trying to take over and I would agree is a better solution. But the only thing pushing Flash out is phones/tablets.

Comment: I disagree. The "thing pushing flash out" is its bad quality. It is notoriously known for endless security flaws.

Comment: True and the fact you need to download a player to run Flash. Thank you for the advice

Comment: I think your question is suffering from a lack of focus -- if you can reduce your question to a few lines of code or a specific problem you've run in to, that might help get some more answers. For example, I'm very confused about the need for the xml file; what purpose does that serve? Instead of making your click counter a static xml file, just make it an SQL query.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Thank you for your response and I understand the problem with this question after re-reading it. I think I have decided to move this from a flash player to HTML5. I will try to make it an SQL Query first though, seems like good practice. I feel I have a better understanding of how to do this in HTML5 compared to Flash since this is my first time trying to incorporate a flash player. Thank you again for all the comments and assistance.